# Telegram bot corrompe archivo .xlsx al enviarlo

Tags: python, telegram

tengo el siguiente código que envía un archivo excel mediante un bot y requests.

```
requests.post(f'https://api.telegram.org/bot{bot_token}/sendDocument',
    files={'document': (ruta+filename, ruta+filename),
                },
    data={'chat_id': chat_id, 'caption': filename})
```

El problema es que al abrir el archivo por el chat de Telegram, esta roto, Excel no lo lee.

Este mismo código uso para enviar archivos PDF, pero no se porqué corrompe el archivo xlsx.
Agradezco su tiempo.

Comment: Tal vez la codificación es diferente, ayudaría que des más detalles

Comment: Disculpa, qué más detalles sería conveniente aportar?
el mensaje que aparece en excel es:
Excel no puede abrir el archivo 'Immobiliarias.xlsx' porque el formato o la extensión no son validos. Compruebe que le archivo no se ha dañado y que la extensión y el formato del archivo coinciden.